# set up font awesome 5 in angular-cli 8 for angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add fontawesome 5 to my angular-cli 8.0.2 project (with scss) by copy fonts to project (not link them from internet) and without using any external plugins/projects but in direct way.

So I create project and install fontawesome (free) [via npm](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#installing-free) as follows

```
ng n --style=scss --routing=true myproject
cd myproject
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

I modify files:

- In `angular.json` in key `projects.myproject.architect.build.options.styles` I add following value to array

  `"./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss"`
- In `styles.scss` I add line:

  `@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";`
- In `src/app/app.component.html` after `Wellcome` text I add

  `<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>`

Then I run command `ng serve` and go in browser to `http://localhost:4200/` and see this:

[image]

I use different instructions from internet but this is best result that I get - but still doesn't work (we see square instead [this icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/sync-alt?style=solid)). **What to do to fix this problem?**

Comment: Any reason why you're importing the same SCSS file twice?

Comment: when I not change `styles.scss` then 'square icon' will be not visible

Comment: What about try removing the import in your `styles.scss` file and instead import the `all.css` file from `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css` into `angular.json`?

Comment: Most likely it doesn't work because the path specified in the fa.scss is not correct for your project, meaning the browser can't find a font at this place and therefore only rendering squares. But to verify this you would have to debug this with the developer tools and see which font file is loaded (by looking at the network tab in the dev tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The reason why the icons don't display is that you didn't specify the type of icon style. You can find a list of supported icon styles [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass) (or listed below):

- `brands.scss`
- `solid.scss`
- `regular.scss`
- `light.scss`

---

## Original answer

The SCSS file that FontAwesome includes in its NPM package does not set itself up for you: you're supposed to import the individual SCSS files yourself. (See the [docs on the SCSS part](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass) for more info)

Instead, you should include the already compiled CSS so that you don't have to import the SCSS files manually. (Run the command below to set the style)

```
ng config projects.myproject.architect.build.options.styles "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
```

(Or manually add `"./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"` to your project's styles)

For more info on what FontAwesome includes in its package, refer to the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers).

Comment: I only change import in **styles.css** to `@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";` and it works :) - thank you

Answer (score 7):

Font Awesome now provides [Font Awesome Angular component](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome), but you can also use the following plain approach:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Load Font Awesome icons by just simply adding the following into `styles.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
```

Tested on Angular `v8.2.14` and Angular CLI `v8.3.19`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. I was missing the "@" took me hours to find it.